# Capturing mouse movement while moused pressed in Java

Tags: java, mouse, listener

I'm trying to get the mouse position while pressing the mouse button but it doesn't work.
I'm extending the `MouseAdapter` and as stated at the Javadoc the `mouseMove()` is invoked when the mouse cursor has been moved onto a component but no buttons have been pushed.

This is an example class I have created to show you my problem:

```
public class TestMouse extends MouseAdapter{

    int x,y;
    boolean pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        pressed = true;
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        pressed = false;
    }

    /*
    Invoked when the mouse is not pressed only.
    */
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
    }   


    /*
    I want something like that.
    */
    public void mousePressedAndMoved(MouseEvent e){
        ....
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried mouseDragged() ?

Answer (score 3):

That's the problem with `MouseAdapter`, since it's a `abstract class` and not an `interface` (`MouseMotionListener` is the one you need), it gives empty implementations for all the possible events just to avoid you from being forced to override them all, this also implies that you could miss some of these events if you don't read docs.

If you look carefully at [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) though, you will see that you have

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
```

that you can override to listen exactly to what you need.

Comment: What else you need? You are already overriding `mouseMoved`, that's the same, just called in a different situation.